# Make a facebook like button on a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-like

I am making a list in my page and i want to add a like button on each item. How can i do that?

I use this to specify a different url on each item :

```
content_tag :iframe, nil, :src => "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=#{url}&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=80", :scrolling => 'no', :frameborder => '0', :allowtransparency => true, :id => :facebook_like, :style => "border:none; overflow:hidden; width:70px; height:25px;"
```

On the url in the like button, i put custom meta but facebook does not use it. It only use the meta of my list page.

How can i do to force facebook to use the metas of the liked page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How an i do to force facebook to use the metas of the liked page?
```

You cannot force Facebook to use the metas, as they do it automatically from the URL you give to them.  They lint it.  You can see the linter in action at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

**EDIT**
Per the comments below:

The page where the like button is located has the following iframe specified:

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoteletlodge.fr%2Fhotel&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=80
```

So the page being liked is itself: http://hoteletlodge.fr/hotel

To have that like button like to the http://hoteletlodge.fr/hotel/inde/maharajas-express page, you will need to change the iframe's href to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoteletlodge.fr%2Fhotel%2Finde%2Fmaharajas-express&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=80
```

When you get that changed on http://hoteletlodge.fr/hotel , then you will need to fix the og errors on the maharajas page. See:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhoteletlodge.fr%2Fhotel%2Finde%2Fmaharajas-express

Comment: I just want to facebook get the metas of the url liked and not the meta of the url where the like button is.

Comment: Facebook already does get the metas of the url liked.  It could care less about the metas on the page where the like button is located.

Comment: What's the URL that has the like button. And what's the URL of the item being liked?

Comment: I would like to like this url : http://www.hoteletlodge.fr/hotel/inde/maharajas-express  from the url : http://www.hoteletlodge.fr/hotel